# Tensorflow returns same weights in hidden layer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a model that will emulate a sine function.
Using 3 fully connected layers with 1-15-1 neurons. So I have 2 weight variables, 1x15 and 15x1. After training they have the same values:

```
[[0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432664] 
[0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432664] 
[0.02432664] [0.02432664] [0.02432665] [0.02432665] [0.02432665]]

[[0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664
  0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664 0.02432664
  0.02432665 0.02432665 0.02432665]]
```

Here is my code:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([15, 1]) * 0.3)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1, 15]) * 0.3)
label = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, None])
result = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)

l1 = tf.matmul(W1, label)
l2 = tf.matmul(W2, l1)
loss = tf.square(l2 - result)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss)
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)


sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
feed_dict = {label: [labels], result: values}

for i in range(0, 500):
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict)
```

Values and labels from feed_dict look like this:

```
[0.041410759078128294, 0.5139904997395468, 0.97, 0.9710565162951535, 
 0.6471067811865476, 0.20643446504023055]

[1, 15, 50, 60, 75, 95]
```

(Range 1-100 equivalent to 0 - PI)

Have no idea why tensorflow is doing so. Can you suggest what has gone wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not randomly initializing your weights matrices `W1` and `W2`. You're using:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([15, 1]) * 0.3)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1, 15]) * 0.3)
```

But you should be initializing them using something like a random normal distribution:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((15,1), stddev=0.01)/tf.sqrt(n))
```

This is because no what what the input is, if all weights are initialized to the same values, as in your case, all units in the hidden layer will be the same, and your network won't be able to learn.

Comment: The weights are changing now, thank you.
But the network does not learn anything but linear function (instead of sine). Can you help me once again?

Comment: You're only learning a linear function because there are no activations in the graph. I don't know about sine, but if you wanted sigmoid nonlinearity you would just write `W1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(W1)` after you create the weight matrix for `W1`.